# Is it possible to make Eclipse sidebar autohide?

Tags: eclipse

Have a tiny question here.

Is it possible for me to make the package explorer autohide like I can do with Windows's taskbar(on autohide)?

I know there is fast view, and I do use it, but autohide would be even better. Is it possible to set an option for it somewhere?

Comment: Related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=56119

Answer (score 1):

You can use the icon *Minimize* of a (group) view like *Package Explorer* and it will minimize to an icon bar on the side. From the icon bar, you can press the icon to view the window, make a selection or press `<Esc>` to let it minimize again.

To get the (group) view back, you need to press the icon *Restore*, and the view will restore.